# Set the execution directory in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible, to execute a class in a specified directory?

I mean, a.class is in directory abc and i want it to be executed as if it were in directory xyz.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Absolutely.

Go into the Debug/Run dialog (drop down button next to the bug/"go" buttons), and in the Arguments tab, set the Working Directory by selecting "Other" and then putting in the relevant directory name. Note that the directory can use "variables" like `$workspace_loc`. You can even make it prompt the user using `$folder_prompt`.