# Eclipse c++ debugging executable is not finding the file with relative path

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I have a project that has more makefiles. At some specific folders, there are some makefiles that can create binaries/executables. I right-click on the makefile and do a `Make Tarkgets -> Build -> all`, so I get the executable right there. If I run the executable from console, it works fine, but if I do a right-click on it and `Debug as -> Local C/C++ Application`, it runs but at some point it is reading a file with relative path:

```
FILE *f = fopen(fName, "rb"); // fname is a relative path : ../../../path/to/file

if(f == NULL)
{
    perror(fName);
    exit(2);
}
```

and it is not finding it; the pointer is empty/NULL. To me it seems like Eclipse is searching for the file from the place where the project was opened, not from where the executable is. I suppose this because if I create a project from the makefile that created the executable, it works, it finds the file. But from that place I cannot see the sources, so, for placing breakpoints I have to run step-in by step-in until I get in the right place/right source.

Can anyone help me to fix this thing? Is there a way to make it search the file from the place where the executable is? Thanks

P.S. : I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180103/relative-path-with-fstream-c), it's similar, but it did not pointed me to anything...

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! And uise `nullptr`, not the C-style `NULL` macro.

Comment: well, it's a huge project with C and C++ code in it :)

Comment: When you start the debugger, you might end up in the debugger's directory and not in your program's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess work directory is different for both cases, and thats why you can not open your file. Try to use absolute path for `fopen()` or look for a way to specify proper work directory for the second case.

There is a way to modify the working directory, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/329141/3062311):

- right-click on binary/executable `Debug As -> Debug Configuration ...`
- in `Arguments` tab, in the bottom, there is a `Working directory:` area, uncheck the `Use default` and add the correct path (where is the executable/binary). The buttons `Workspace...` and `File System...` may help

Comment: Can you help me to "fix" it? I'd like to put it in the right place

Comment: I cannot use absolute path because it will not work for other computers...

Comment: So, is there a way to set the working directory?

Comment: @sop Probably there should be some setting for debug session, that you start. You should refer to debugger docs.

Comment: Thank you, I found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329129/set-the-execution-directory-in-eclipse)