# Setting Project working directory in Eclipse when working with relative paths

Tags: java, eclipse, relative-path

I have workspace where I save all my java projects worked in Eclipse.
Let's call it `D:\Workspace\`. I have a project in said workspace which route lets say is: `D:\Workspace\DoubleDotting\`.

In said Java project, in the main method, I create a file object in the following way:

> File doubleDotted = new File("**..**\Folder1\file.xyz");

At the moment of exporting the program as a runnable Jar into `D:\Projects\DoubleDotting\Folder2\`, the program executes just fine, for `D:\Projects\DoubleDotting\Folder1\file.xyz` exists.

However `file.xyz` does not exist in `D:\Workspace\DoubleDotting\Folder1\`, so naturally when running/debugging the program from Eclipse, I get a `FileNotFoundException`.

Working with relative paths, is an amazing time-saver when working on generic programs that can be applied to multiple directories with a similar working structure, however it's a headache to debug within Eclipse.

**Is there a way to change a project's working directory virtually within Eclipse** or is the lazy option of creating such folders/files within the Project directory, the only solution to running/debugging within eclipse?

Comment: You can set the working directory in the launch configuration (which is by default the project directory): https://stackoverflow.com/a/329141/6505250

Answer (score 0):

Lets be clever on this. If you would only create simple class in root of your project, you could simply see where `.`(current directory) is pointing to.
Eg

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
}
```

This will show you where current directory from runtime point of view is located. Build your relative path on top of that.

Comment: Indeed. I was working with a similar workaround: `.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()`, however, I think your solution might be smarter.